Spring Batch : Adding TaskExecutor bean on my config causes errors
I have a basic Spring Boot batch application (reading datas from SQL Database, processing it and updating in the same SQL database). I don't put the code as it is long but it's very basic.
My application just works fine. But when adding this bean on my config :
@Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(3);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }

My application fails :
2024-04-21T16:50:48.672+02:00  INFO 26436 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=analyseJob]] failed unexpectedly and fatally with the following parameters: [{}]

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466) ~[spring-orm-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601) ~[spring-tx-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:376) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:283) ~[spring-core-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:638) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.22.Final.jar:6.2.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:696) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.22.Final.jar:6.2.22.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.22.Final.jar:6.2.22.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:584) ~[spring-orm-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487) ~[spring-orm-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:733) ~[spring-orm-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy100.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:484) ~[spring-orm-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.18.jar:6.0.18]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:376)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:283)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:584)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:733)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy100.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:484)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:409)
    ... 12 more

